# How to refer a Google Closure function in ClojureScript?

Tags: clojurescript

This is how you require a google closure function namespace:

```
(ns example.core
  (:require
    [goog.string :as gstring]
    goog.string.format))
```

But how do you refer some functions, I tried this:

```
(ns example.core
  (:require
    [goog.string :as gstring :refer [format]]
    goog.string.format))
```

But it doesn't work, it complains with: `Invalid :refer, var goog.string/format does not exist`

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Insofar as the `ns` form is structured, `:refer` essentially works the same for Closure libraries as it does for ClojureScript namespaces. So this form

```
(ns example.core
 (:require
   [goog.string :as gstring :refer [capitalize]]))
```

would refer `capitalize`.

But, `goog.string.format` is a special namespace that doesn't really follow the rules; it is best to just follow the examples at https://clojurescript.org/reference/google-closure-library#requiring-a-function

Comment: So is this a current limitation? In that it's simply not possible as of ClojureScript 1.9 to refer this kind of JavaScript functions? Thus only the alias access or the fully qualified works?

Comment: @DidierA. I think your example referring `format` is probably OK. Are you using self-hosted ClojureScript? If so, that just might be a current limitation especially if the `capitalize` example doesn't work for you.

Answer (score -1):

Use `import` instead:

```
(ns example.core
    (:import
        [goog.string format]))

(println (format "% 10.2f" -123.456))
```

Comment: `:use` / `:only` is a dual form of `:require` / `:refer`, so the above is the same as `(ns example.core (:require [goog.string :as string :refer [format]]))` which fails with `TypeError: goog.string.format is not a function`